# Android date/time wheel picker

Tags: android, datepicker, datetimepicker, timepicker

How can I achieve this layout for a time picker (and also for a date picker)? The default layout is either a (very big) clock or a (not beautiful) spinner style time picker. I saw this in several apps but couldn't find how to achieve this look and feel.

[image]

Comment: you can check time-picker in android here is some links just check http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_timepicker_control.htm          http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-time-picker-example/                       http://androidexample.com/Time_Picker_With_AM_PM_Values_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=86&aaid=109

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_timepicker_control.htm shows the time picker layout I want but it seems to be the default time picker though I don't see it like that in my preview (using latest api 22). I see it as a spinner with up/down buttons.

Answer (score 8):

For future reference for anyone that might need this, it is possible to achieve this time picker spinner by just choosing a TimePicker among the android widgets and then, on the xml file, type `android:timePickerMode="spinner"`.

Your widget xml code should look like this:

```
<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/timePicker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:timePickerMode="spinner" />
```

My answer was based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html).

Answer (score 6):

Simplest way to achieve this in my view is since api level 21:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timePicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:timePickerMode="spinner" />

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datePicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:calendarViewShown="false"
        android:datePickerMode="spinner" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You get this:

[image: Date Time Picker Example]

Answer (score 1):

This example has three pickers: NumberPicker, DatePicker and TimerPicker.

https://github.com/rodrigobusata/android-pickers

or

Use only the sample without the library and override for Android default pickers.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "Use only the sample without the library and override for Android default pickers"?

Comment: Your Wellcome. In this sample there is a sample using a library that override the Android default pickers for can change the colors, but case you want only use a picker with the default colors, see only sample that is inside app folder and override "net.simonvt.timepicker.TimePicker" to "TimePicker".

Comment: As far as I understand, I need the net.simonvt.datepicker.DatePicker (for example) implementation in order to see the look and feel I want, where can I find it in order to use it in my code? in the link I only see a reference to it but not the actual implementation, what am I missing?

Comment: They are in sample next to "app" folder there are the folders "numberpicker-library", "datepicker-libray" and "timerpicker-library".

Comment: So I need to take the sources from here: https://github.com/rodrigobusata/android-pickers/tree/master/timerpicker-library/src/main/java/net/simonvt/timepicker and then I will be able to use them in the layout inside my app?

Comment: Weird, apparently the ugly spinner was only in the preview, when I actually run the app, it looks as I want it to be

Comment: This because in your preview may be greater than your emulator.

Comment: I think the link is no more

Answer (score 0):

You should note that this Dialog is a Fragment.

That said, the main idea will be this:
When you need to launch this Date Picker, then you will show that fragment as an overlay of the current activity. This fragment has a date picked listener: an event that is launched when  the user picks a date. Ok, everything easy until here. The hardest thing to understand will be the last one: Interaction between the fragment and the activity. What for? Because the Activity needs to know whick Date was selected. To achieve this the Fragment will have a public Interface that will be implemented by the activity.

Ok, let's see the code:

**MyActivity.java**

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity implements DatePickerFragment.FragmentInteraction{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        Button showDatePickerButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.dateButton);
        showDatePickerButtonsetOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
                newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), getString(R.string.datePickerTitle));
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void doSomethingWithDate(int day, int month, int year) {
        Log.d("", "SELECTED DATE " + month + "/" + day  + "/" + year);
    }
}
```

**DatePickerFragment.java**

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

    private FragmentInteraction mListener;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mListener = (FragmentInteraction) activity;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Show picker with actual date presetted
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int anio, int mes, int dia) {
        mListener.doSomethingWithDate(dia, mes + 1, anio);
    }

    public interface FragmentInteraction{
        public void doSomethingWithDate(int dia, int mes, int anio);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your reply. I want a time/date picker component to be placed on a fragment with other components where the user can select a date/time. My question was regarding the layout of the time picker component.

Comment: The just use the DatePickerFragment class only and skip the interface

Comment: So it can't be used as a simple object/component/view in a layout along with other objects/components/views? for example: a date picker, a textview and a button inside the same layout?

Comment: Yes, of course. But is not a simple component. It's a fragment component

Answer (score 0):

Simply add timepickermode in xml like this 
         `<TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:timePickerMode="spinner"
        android:text="TimePicker"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>`